# How to refactor UICollectionViewController to UIViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I currently have a `storyboard` scene where the view controller for the scene is a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` and thus the root view is a `UICollectionView`. I would like to change this custom view controller into a generic `UIViewController` that implements the `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol instead, and make the root view a `UIView` with the collection view as a subview.

However, if I change my view controller to a subclass of `UIViewController`, its entry in the storyboard gains a 'view' outlet (this is good) but I cannot embed the existing `UICollectionView` into a `UIView` (interface builder still has this option greyed out)

So what is the simplest, least painful way to refactor the `storyboard` into my desired `UIViewController -> UIView -> UICollectionView` hierarchy? I do not want to have to re-create the scene from scratch.

Comment: I think the correct way is to create new scene.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution can be having a container view inside the UIViewController and give embedded segue to your existing UICollectionViewController as displayed below:

[image]

Comment: But this results in a UIViewController -> UICollectionViewController hierarchy. So while it is an alternative, it's not the UIViewController <UICollectionViewDelegate> -> UIView -> UICollectionView arrangement that I'm seeking